# How to get caps/num/scroll lock keys OSD notification?

Tags: notification, notify-osd, capslock, numlock

I would like to have a OSD notification display briefly everytime the CAPS, Num, or Scroll Lock state toggles.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

There is already an application that attempts to do this called [`indicator-keylock`](https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock). You need a PPA to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
setsid indicator-keylock  # to run it the first time
```

But I'd be interested to see if there's a neat way to bind onto these lock-toggle events.

Comment: Thanks, the app you mentioned also includes an icon on the systray...I would prefer for something that is invisible, but notifies via OSD when the corresponding Key is pressed.

Comment: Or is there an option on `indicator-keylock` to remove the system tray indicator?

Comment: awesome app but the icons don't look good. Do you know where can I edit them